# Identity fie in GIT_SSH_COMMAND for Windows not accessible

Tags: windows, git, ssh

This command not working for me. I need to pass tmp identity file to ssh (git):

`set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -F /dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Temp\git-ssh-key" &  git clone git@some_repo.git`

I get a Warning:

`Identity file C:Userssome_userAppDataLocalTempgit-ssh-key not accessible: No such file or directory.`

When I try double backslash in identity file path, got a error:

`debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\assorvin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\git-ssh-key Load key "C:\\Users\\some_user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\git-ssh-key": invalid format`

Comment: What about surrounding the path in escaped quotes? `-c \"C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Temp\git-ssh-key\" "`

Comment: same result: not accessible: No such file or directory

Comment: What about using forward slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work using linux-style path with

```sh
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -F /dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /C/Users/some_user/AppData/Local/Temp/git-ssh-key"&&  git clone git@some_repo.git
```

Note the lack of space before the `&&`: it avoid adding an extra space to the previous command, which can be sometimes problematic.